# Отследить серию нажатий на горячую клавишу QAction

Tags: c++, qt5

Действия в программе я определяю через QAction. Поведение стандартное: горячая клавиша нажата - выполняется присоединенный слот.

**А вопрос вот в чем ...**

В присоединенном слоте мне нужно выполнить два действия:

- изменить некоторый счетчик
- выполнить небольшой пересчет данных на основе нового значения счетчика

Нужно не выполнять пересчет (а только модифицировать счетчик) если горячая клавиша зажата. И только потом, когда эта клавиша отпущена - выполнить необходимый расчет.

Используя QAction возможно ли такое, или нужно залезать в обработчик событий и уже там ловить моменты отпускания клавиши? Второе очень бы не хотелось, если есть решение проще.

Comment: А использовать событие отпускания клавиши, а не нажатия?

Comment: Я вообще пока "отвязан" от событий. Пока решается только средствами QAction и их привязкой к слотам. Смотрю, наверное придется воспользоваться `void QWidget::actionEvent(QActionEvent *event)`, переписать ее под себя.